# Andengine: FontException Not enough space for letter

Tags: android, andengine

Im developing a game with andengine. And I'm playing with fonts. I was applying different fonts with different font size and I encountered this problem.

Its font exception and says":

**"FontException Not enough space for letter 'ủ' " on the BitmapTextureAtlas.**

Im new to AndEngine. Anyone can help me fix it. Thanks!

Here's LogCat Snapshot of Exception:

[image: FontException]

Answer (score 4):

This may seems ridiculous, but you need to make your texture bigger, or make your font size smaller.

Remember when creating a font, you have to specify a texture. If you are using example code from andengine, your texture is probably 256x256 pixels. If your font is a large size, it will fill up that texture and not have enough room to draw the remaining characters. Try making that texture bigger, say 256x512, for example.

That will do it.

See below:

```
this.mFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

this.mFont = new Font(this.mFontTexture, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32, true, Color.BLACK);
```

on the line that creates the BitmapTextureAtlas, the first to arguments are the width and height of the texture that your font is drawn to. Try bigger numbers. I bet increasing just one dimension will do it.

Comment: How can you know how big to actually make it without going completely overkill? And what makes you say to go `256 x 512` as opposed to `512 x 512`? I'm having this problem too and would like to more.

Comment: Unless you want to use a bitmap font generator, you will have to guess. (here's one for example: http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)Even with that, Andengine will vary somewhat, so it just gets you in the ballpark.
My reason for picking 256x512 is that people tend to forget with power-of-two textures they do not have to both dimensions the same.